# Get Product ID after add in PHP Prestashop Module

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I've writed a function like this:

```
public function addProduct($data){
    $object = new Product();
    foreach($data as $k=>$v){
        $object->{$k} = $v;
    }
    //$object->updateCategories($data['category'], true);
    if($object->save()){
        return $object->add();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It work fine, but I need to return the Product ID.
I've tried with:

```
Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
```

But it return `'0'`

Comment: Note that $object->add() and $object->save() do the same thing, so you should replace the if/else with return $object->save();

Comment: Yes thanks, I found this bug by testing the function

Answer (score 2):

I've read the AdminImportController.php, the solution is simple:

```
return $object->id;
```